# How can I edit the label after button is pressed

Tags: python, tkinter

```
button = Button(frame, text = "...", font = ('Courier', 14), command = lambda: principal_function(entry.get()))
button.place(relx = 0.7, relwidth = 0.3, relheight = 1)

label:

generalLabel = Label(lower_frame, text = '..', font = ("Courier", 22))
generalLabel.place(relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)`enter code here`
generalLabel.pack()
```

I want to update the label with a new text if button is pressed

Comment: There are dozens of similar questions on this site. Did you do any research before asking this question? If you tell us what you searched on, perhaps we can optimize one of the duplicates so that it's easier to find.

Answer (score 2):

This should work, updating the config of the label

```
generalLabel.config(text="changed")
```